# Parsing JSON into a struct

Tags: json, parsing, go

I have successfully parsed JSON into structs when they have a regular key-value format.

However, how can I parse a JSON like this:

```
{
  "count": 2,
  "results": [{ key: "workspaces", id: "10" }, { key: "workspaces", id: "11" }],
  "workspaces": {
    "10": {
      id: "10",
      title: "some project",
      participant_ids: ["2", "6"],
      primary_counterpart_id: "6"
    },
    "11": {
      id: "11",
      title: "another project",
      participant_ids: ["2", "8"],
      primary_counterpart_id: "8"
    }
  }
}
```

Where the keys for the `workspaces` section is not defined ahead of time, but instead holds the workspace id?

My initial structs were:

```
type WorkspaceRequest struct {
    Count      int64       `json:"count"`
    Workspaces []Workspace `json:"workspaces"`
}

type Workspace struct {
    Title string `json:"title"`
}
```

How can I get a list of Workspaces from the shown JSON?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you're representing `Workspaces` as an array in your model but it's a dictionary/map in the json. Just make it a `map[sting]Workspace` and you should be good. First item would be had with `instance.Workspaces["11"]`

A couple hints as to how I knew that; 1) Workspaces is opened with a brace `{`, an array is never the right type for this (they always are enclosed by `[]` in json), it's an object or a map. 2) the items within it are denoted like `"11": { ... }`. That means if I represent it with an object in Go I need a property named `11`, `12` ect, it's pretty safe to assume that's not what you want here meaning it must be a map.

Comment: Thank you so much. When you answered, it became obvious. But the same is true for almost all hard problems :)